# Search in 3 fields Data PHP

Tags: php, pdo

in my PHP database there is a search option to search name or email and it is work fine with below code but i have another field also called mobile it is not searching with the code  so how to modify the below code please

thanks

code below

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name LIKE ? or email LIKE ?");

$stmt->execute(["%" . $_POST['search'] . "%", "%" . $_POST['search'] . "%"]);
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Adding another field to that query should be fairly obvious to all but .....

Comment: any other method to search at least 3 fields ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add another test to the WHERE Clause and then add another value into the array passed to the `execute()` method.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * 
                        FROM table1 
                        WHERE name LIKE ? 
                           OR email LIKE ?
                           OR mobile LIKE ?");

$stmt->execute(["%$_POST[search]%", 
                "%$_POST[search]%",
                "%$_POST[search]%"
               ]);
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
```